# wysiwyg editor for aptana studio beginners

Tags: web, aptana, wysiwyg, notepad++

I am a new web designer. I have learned HTML5 and CSS3. However, I find it difficult to burst forward without a WYSIWYG editor.

I want to be able to type in the code I have learned, or carefully gathered, but I also want to be able to see it working, immediately, so that I can be assured that I am on the right track.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way for me to combine Aptana Studio (or Notepad++) with a WYSIWYG view, as I type in the code and build the new website?

Please help me. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, no way to combine Aptana Studio(or Notepad++) has get WYSIWYG editor. But you can try the others free WYSIWYG editors to fulfill your desire. Below software may be very useful for you.

- [Nvu](http://net2.com/nvu/screenshots.html)
- [Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/)
- [pagebreeze](http://www.pagebreeze.com/)
- [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a popular post:

As of Dec 2016, the most popular and useful solution seems to be [Adobe Brackets](http://brackets.io/).

It has the Live Preview feature, where you can see changes in browser immediately as you type.